# flutter getx, getview with two controllers

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, state-management, flutter-getx, flutter-state

I'm a little bit confused with how GetView works. I currently have a page that needs to have at least 2 different controllers. From what I've seen, people mostly use GetView as opposed to Get.find() for better code format, however GetView seems to only use 1 controller, for example:

`class HomeScreen extends GetView<HomeController>`

I have tried to google it and haven't found any solution. I also have tried to use

`class HomeScreen extends GetView<HomeController> with GetView<UserController>`

But it gave me an error that says

> The class 'GetView' can't be used as a mixin because it extends a class other than 'Object'.

I would very appreciate if you can give me a solution or a workaround to use GetView with two or more controllers.

**Please note** that **I'm using GetX bindings** (therefore I have already wrote `Get.put(Controller())` in another file) and **I want to avoid using Get.find** in my widget tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please explain what's the usecase of using **GetView** with multiple controllers? It's not supported. Because a view can have multiple controllers but how many?

Therefore, in that case, you should just use the **GetX** widget for different controllers like:

```
GetX<Controller1>(),
GetX<Controller2>(),
```

and so on